# DateTime Range Picker - JQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have been using [this](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) in my current dashboard, The calendar in it is not that user friendly, for e.g. The Year, Month and Time selections are working through a drop down of selection. I would rather like to use [this](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) which has a better calendar. My functional requirements of a date time range picker for my dashboard context are below mentioned

1. Date Range Selection needed
2. A Better calendar like the Bootstrap Calendar mentioned above (with better year, month and time selection)

Can someone suggest me a better opensource plugin/directive that i can use it or if there any-other projects that was made as an enhancement for the following two projects

[Date Range Picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/)

[Eonasdan Bootstrap DateTime Picker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

I also found following interesting projects too - http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-date-time-picker/

But still they aren't fulfilling my requirements.

- Summary

I am using [Date Range Picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) that's the ideal plugin for my requirement but it doesn't have a better calendar selection, I prefer calendar selection like [Bootstrap DateTime Picker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). Can some suggest me a better solution/plugin, if not only way is to take the calendar from [Bootstrap DateTime Picker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)  and merge to the [Date Range Picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/).

Comment: Did you check https://codecanyon.net/item/calentim-date-time-range-picker/20099228

Comment: You could consider using a non-range date picker (like Eonasdan) and simply use two fields, one for start date and one for end date. You would only have to implement logic to avoid selecting an invalid range.